# Alternating cases in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Working on a very simple task to return an uncapped string as capitals and vice versa, so for example:

```
"hello world".to_alternating_case() === "HELLO WORLD"
"HELLO WORLD".to_alternating_case() === "hello world"
"hello WORLD".to_alternating_case() === "HELLO world"
"HeLLo WoRLD".to_alternating_case() === "hEllO wOrld"
"12345".to_alternating_case() === "12345" // Non-alphabetical characters are unaffected
"1a2b3c4d5e".to_alternating_case() === "1A2B3C4D5E"
"String.prototype.toAlternatingCase".to_alternating_case() === "sTRING.PROTOTYPE.TOaLTERNATINGcASE"
```

My initial thought was to use the swapcase method, which should work. But there's something wrong with my code and I can't quite figure it out.

```
class String
  def to_alternating_case(word)
 
    word.swapcase
  end
end

word = String.new
```

The error message:

```
#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)>
main.rb:4:in `to_alternating_case'
```

Here is a [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56efc695740d30f963000557/train/ruby) to the kata

Comment: You define your method for expecting a single argument, but when calling it, you don't provide an argument. This is what the error message (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)) tells you.

Comment: @user1934428 the method calls are given as test examples, the OP has to provide the implementation. (check out the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding an instance method to the `String` class, that method already operates on the string instance. There's no need to pass the string as an argument, just send `swapcase` to `self`: (you don't have to specify `self` explicitly since it is the default [receiver](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver))

```
class String
  def to_alternating_case
    swapcase
  end
end

'Hello, world!'.to_alternating_case
#=> "hELLO, WORLD!"
```

Or even shorter via [`alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#alias_method-method):

```
String.alias_method :to_alternating_case, :swapcase

'Hello, world!'.to_alternating_case
#=> "hELLO, WORLD!"
```

Note that it's not recommended to patch Ruby's core classes. It's fine for solving your kata but for actual code, you should define your methods in a separate module / class and pass the string. (just like in your attempt)

Comment: omg that was it! definitely need to go back and revisit classes and instances haha =D

Comment: @Stefan: Can we really say, that monkeypatching is not recommended, in particular since Rails use it a lot? I'm also thinking of suggestions like [this](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/), which teach about controlled ways of monkeypatching.

Comment: @user1934428 yes absolutely. If you want to add a method, then monkey patching it into one of Ruby's core classes isn't the recommended way. There might be a few special cases where this is desired. But in general, you shouldn't touch the built-in classes. (let alone recommending such programming style)

Comment: so what if you wanted to map over a string and capitalize the start of every word in a class? it doesn't recognise ```map or (&:capitalize)```

Answer (score 0):

From your usage example (i.e. `"HeLLo WoRLD".to_alternating_case() === "hEllO wOrld"`), it seems that you want `to_alternating_case` have the same effect than `swapcase`. You can do this with

```
class String
  alias_method :to_alternating_case, :swapcase
end
```

or

```
class String
  alias swapcase to_alternating_case
end
```